# Preselect Rows In Lightning Datatable (Aura lightning Component)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-datatable, aura-iteration, aura-if

I am developing an aura lightning component which is "called" through a visualforce page.

The functionality consists of two aura lightning components:

1. Parent aura lightning component: consists of a lightning card in which i have created a table. Within that table another aura lightning component is called (child)
2. Child aura lightning component: This component is called through the parent component. It consists of information provided by the parent aura lightning component and by pressing a "Search" button a modal pops up which consists of a lightning datatable which is filled in with data retrieved by apex. (part of code below)

   ```
        <td class="slds-text-align_right" role="gridcell" >
        </td>
        <th scope="row">
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="OfferMember" >{!v.offerMemberData.offerMember.Name}</div>
        </th>

        <c:el_sObjectLookup objectAPIName = "Account"    fieldAPINames = "Name,el_TIN__c" subHeadingFieldsAPI = "el_TIN__c"
                            lookupIcon = "standard:account" placeholder = "Search Account"
                            selectedRecordId= "{!v.currentAccount}"/>


        <td role="gridcell" >
            <div class="slds-truncate" title="Subscription" ><ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="subscription" name="{!index}" label="" disabled="{!v.disabled}" change="{!c.onSubscrClick}"/></div>
        </td>
        <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.offerToBeDisplayed))}">
            <td role="gridcell" >
                <div class="slds-truncate" title="Selected Offer" >{!v.offerToBeDisplayed}</div>
            </td>
            <td role="gridcell">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small" aria-haspopup="false" tabindex="0" title="Edit Button">
                    <span class="slds-assistive-text" data-id="{!index}"></span>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <lightning:button label="Edit" iconName="utility:edit" value="{!index}" name="{!v.offerMemberData.offerMember.Id}" class="{!v.isActiveSubscription}" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleSearch}"/>  
                    <lightning:button label="Remove" iconName="utility:delete" value="{!index}" name="{!v.offerMemberData.offerMember.Id}" class="{!v.isActiveSubscription}" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleRemove}"/>
                    <!--onclick="{!c.handleSearch}"-->
                </button>
            </td>
            <aura:set attribute="else">

                <td role="gridcell">
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small" aria-haspopup="false" tabindex="0" title="Search Button">
                        <span class="slds-assistive-text" data-id="{!index}"></span>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <lightning:button label="Search" iconName="utility:search" value="{!index}" name="{!v.offerMemberData.offerMember.Id}" class="{!v.isActiveSubscription}" iconPosition="left" onclick="{!c.handleSearch}"/>  
                        <!--onclick="{!c.handleSearch}"-->
                    </button>
                </td>
            </aura:set>
        </aura:if>
    </tr>



    <!-- Use LARGE modal/Pop-up Box to display Datatable.-->  
    <!--Use aura:if tag to display/hide popup based on isModalOpen value-->  
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
        <div class="slds-m-around_xx-large" >
            <!-- Modal/Popup Box starts here-->
            <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
                <div class="slds-modal__container">
                    <!--loading spinner start-->
                    <div class="slds-is-relative">
                        <aura:if isTrue="{!v.spinner}">
                            <div aura:id="spinnerId" class="slds-spinner_container">
                                <div class="slds-spinner--brand  slds-spinner slds-spinner--medium slds-is-relative" role="alert">
                                    <span class="slds-assistive-text">Loading</span>
                                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-a"></div>
                                    <div class="slds-spinner__dot-b"></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </aura:if>
                        <!--Loading spinner end-->

                        <!-- Modal/Popup Box Header Starts here-->
                        <header class="slds-modal__header">
                            <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:close"
                                                  onclick="{! c.closeModel }"
                                                  alternativeText="close"
                                                  variant="bare-inverse"
                                                  class="slds-modal__close"/>
                            <h2 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Configuration Selection</h2>
                        </header>
                        <!-- Modal/Popup Box Header Ends here-->

                        <!--Modal/Popup Box Body Starts here-->

                        <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">

                            <lightning:datatable aura:id="infoTable" columns="{! v.columns }" data="{! v.data }" keyField="Id"  maxRowSelection="1" 
                                                 showRowNumberColumn="false" onrowselection="{!c.configurationSelection}" selectedRows="{!v.selectedRows}" />
                        </div>
                        <!--Modal/Popup Box Body Ends here-->

                        <!--Modal/Popup Box Footer Starts here-->
                        <footer class="slds-modal__footer">
                            <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Cancel" title="Cancel" onclick="{! c.closeModel }"/>
                            <aura:if isTrue="{!not(empty(v.offerToBeDisplayed))}">
                                <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Save" title="Save" onclick="{!c.handleEdit}"/> 
                                <aura:set attribute="else">
                                    <lightning:button variant="neutral" label="Add" title="Add" onclick="{!c.storeSelectedOffer}"/>
                                </aura:set>
                            </aura:if>
                        </footer>
                        <!--Modal/Popup Box Footer Ends here-->

                    </div>  <!-- Close spinner relative -->
                </div>
            </section>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.isModalOpen}">
                <!-- Grey Background -->
                <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop_open"></div>
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </aura:if>
   ```

ISSUE:
I need to preselect a row when the modal which contains the lightning datatable is loaded. I tried to do so like in the above code (sample javascript code)

```
var action = component.get("c.getAvailableProductConfigurations");
        action.setParams({ offerMemberId : component.get("v.offerMemberData.offerMember.Id"),
                          isActiveSub : component.get("v.isActiveSubscription"),
                          accountId : component.get("v.currentAccount"),
                          basketId : component.get("v.currentBasketId"),
                          bundledOfferId : component.get("v.bundledOfferId")
                         });
        // Create a callback that is executed after the server-side action returns
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                
                var availableConfigs = response.getReturnValue();
                // set the mapList with the value returned from the server
                component.set("v.availableProdConfigurations", availableConfigs);
                component.set("v.spinner", false); //Set Loading Spinner to False
                //alert(JSON.stringify(availableConfigs));
                
                //check if the returned data contain supplyNumber and decide which datatable will be displayed
                for(var i=0; i<availableConfigs.length; i++){
                    if(availableConfigs[i].supplyNumber != null){
                        component.set('v.columns', [
                            {label: 'Offer Name', fieldName: 'configName', type: 'text'},
                            {label: 'Supply Number', fieldName: 'supplyNumber', type: 'text'},
                            {label: 'Installation Address', fieldName: 'installationAddress', type: 'text'},
                            {label: 'Bill Delivery Address', fieldName: 'billDeliveryAddress', type: 'text'}
                        ]); 
                    }
                    else{
                        component.set('v.columns', [
                            {label: 'Offer Name', fieldName: 'configName', type: 'text'}
                        ]);  
                    }
                }
                component.set( 'v.data', availableConfigs ) ;

                //TRY TO PRESELECT OFFERS BUT NO USE
                var selectedRowsIds = []; 
                
                var vData = component.get("v.data");
                alert('first vData is: '+vData[0].configId);
                selectedRowsIds.push(vData[0].configId);
                
                alert('selectedRowsIds: '+selectedRowsIds);
                    
                component.set("v.selectedRows", selectedRowsIds);
                alert('im after set the preselectedRow');
                var getPreselectedRow = component.get("v.selectedRows");
                alert('getPreselectedRow '+getPreselectedRow);
                
            }......
```

So, basically i am populating a list attribute with an id contained in the specific row (selectedRows) which is defined as value in my lightning datatable in the attribute :selectedRow="{!v.selectedRows}" wihtin the child aura component. I can't make it to work and populate the row i am defining. Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I guess you just need to fix the `keyField="Id"` set this to `configId`, `keyField="configId"`, it should work.

Comment: Really thank you! It worked!